# wso2is XACLM and authentication

Tags: authentication, curl, xacml, wso2-identity-server

Here we go again with another question.
I realize my questions are vague but my knowledge is vague. This hydra is just too large and too wide open, good when you know how to use it but holy heck when you don't.  And if you haven't figured it out I'm not a web person.
I'm currently trying to use WSO2IS only as an authorization manager.
Users going to site will have to log in every time(i know this defeats it's entire purpose) but that's the cards I have been dealt.
Here's the flow I need to have.
1. user goes to https://wso2-dev.h3net.com/hello_world.php
   a. login request
     1. username
     2. password
     3. company_id
   b. creates curl (curl library) to send the 3 items collected at login
     1. need correct url for correct API security
   c. receives TRUE/FALSE ( or some indication) authentication was granted
2. wso2is
  a. hello_world.php has been registered with wso2is
  b. user has been created
  c. role has been created
  d. permissions have been set for role
  e. copied PAP authn_user_claim_based_policy_template, changed made for name and claims username, company_id(used externalid)
  f. TryIt does not work, can't find documentation with enough to tell me what needs to be filled in.
  g. published to PDP

I'M VERY CONFUSED ABOUT WHICH URL AND WHICH FORMAT TO USE TO GET THE AUTHORIZATION?
Below I have tried to use XACML, rather long winded but I'll accept anything I can get working.
    `<?php`
    `print "<html><body>";`
    `print "<p>authorize</p>";`
    $url    = "https://wso2-dev.h3net.com:9443/samlsso";

```
$ch = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE          , true   ); # duplicates -v
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER   , true   );
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER   , false  ); # duplicates -k
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST   , false  ); # duplicates -k
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS       ,
  '<Request xmlns="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:3.0:core:schema:wd-17" CombinedDecision="false" ReturnPolicyIdList="false">
  <Attributes Category="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:3.0:attribute-category:resource">
    <Attribute AttributeId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:resource:resource-id" IncludeInResult="false">
      <AttributeValue DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string">username</AttributeValue>
    </Attribute>
  </Attributes>
  <Attributes Category="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:subject-category:access-subject">
    <Attribute AttributeId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:subject:subject-id" IncludeInResult="false">
      <AttributeValue DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string">gadams</AttributeValue>
    </Attribute>
  </Attributes>
  <Attributes Category="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:3.0:attribute-category:action">
    <Attribute AttributeId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:action:action-id" IncludeInResult="false">
      <AttributeValue DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string">authorize</AttributeValue>
    </Attribute>
  </Attributes>
  </Request> ');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("Content-Type: text/xml"));
$result = curl_exec($ch);
if (curl_errno($ch)) {
    echo 'Error:' . curl_error($ch);
} else {
  print "<p>result = $result</p>\n";
}
curl_close ($ch);
}
print "</body></html>\n";
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the steps in the following blog [post](http://www.webfarmr.eu/2013/04/how-to-send-a-xacml-request-using-curl/). It details how to use curl to POST a XACML request against a PDP.

```
curl -X POST -H 'Content-type:text/xml' -T soap-xacml-request.xml https://localhost:8443/asm-pdp/pdp --cacert pdp.b64.cer --user pep:password
```